# Downgraded from libreoffice 5.4.x to go back to 5.1.x now I can't run any libreoffice program

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

I downgraded from libreoffice 5.4.x to go back to 5.1.x in the repositories now I can't run any libreoffice program.  How can I fix this?

What I did to delete libreoffice 5.4.x

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
I then rebooted the machine
```

Then to reinstall 5.1.x I ran the command.

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-common libreoffice
```

When I click on the icon the flash screen comes on but none of the libreoffice applications will launch.

When I try and launch writer from the terminal using the command `libreoffice --writer`

I get this error message

```
 ~$ libreoffice --writer
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  IconThemeInfo::FileNameToThemeId() called with invalid filename.


Fatal exception: Signal 6
Stack:
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3(+0x394e0)[0x7f996c2004e0]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3(+0x39873)[0x7f996c200873]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3(+0x399a8)[0x7f996c2009a8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x354b0)[0x7f996be324b0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7f996be32428]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7f996be3402a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0x16d)[0x7f9964e9484d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x8d6b6)[0x7f9964e926b6]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x8d701)[0x7f9964e92701]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x8d919)[0x7f9964e92919]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_ZN3vcl13IconThemeInfo17FileNameToThemeIdERKN3rtl8OUStringE+0x13c)[0x7f996ebb340c]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_ZN3vcl13IconThemeInfoC2ERKN3rtl8OUStringE+0x70)[0x7f996ebb3690]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_ZN3vcl16IconThemeScanner18AddIconThemeByPathERKN3rtl8OUStringE+0x5b)[0x7f996ebb427b]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_ZN3vcl16IconThemeScanner26ScanDirectoryForIconThemesERKN3rtl8OUStringE+0x13b)[0x7f996ebb446b]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_ZN3vcl16IconThemeScanner6CreateERKN3rtl8OUStringE+0x63)[0x7f996ebb4553]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(+0x2790fdc)[0x7f996ebaefdc]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_ZN13StyleSettingsC1Ev+0x46)[0x7f996ebaf496]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(+0x27914f6)[0x7f996ebaf4f6]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_ZN11AllSettingsC1Ev+0x46)[0x7f996ebaf676]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_ZN11Application12InitSettingsEP10ImplSVData+0x1e)[0x7f996ebb5fde]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_ZN11Application11GetSettingsEv+0x2d)[0x7f996ebb608d]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libvclplug_gtklo.so(+0x3b502)[0x7f995807f502]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_Z7InitVCLv+0x292)[0x7f996ebbadc2]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(+0x279d9f6)[0x7f996ebbb9f6]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(_Z6SVMainv+0x22)[0x7f996ebbbb02]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmergedlo.so(soffice_main+0xa2)[0x7f996dcb3212]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin[0x4006eb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f996be1d830]
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin[0x400729]
lp@jt-laptop:~$




I'm using:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Why did you only install `libreoffice-common`?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a strange reason the problem looks to be caused by `openjdk-8-jre-headless` not sure why but here's everything I did to get it to work.

1) un-install files

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

2) Find and un-install jdk

```
sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

3) Install libreoffice

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Comment: This discussion says to install openjdk-9 and it will work... but I tried that to no avail. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=882436

Comment: Ah, but after a restart it is now working.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-common
```

installed only a few packages but not the applications (Base, Calc, Writer, ...) of the LibreOffice project.
What you want to do is

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Comment: I Installed that but now another error pops up
`sudo apt-get install libreoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libreoffice is already the newest version (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
`  I've also updated the error that happens in the original question